# Attempting to render JSX element but getting undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, jsx, react-d3

So I have this JSX element that I am attempting to render in the Class component. It is essentially a visual provided by D3's React library. However, I am receiving this error upon attempting to render the D3 visual:

`Unhandled Rejection (Error): Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

Below are some relevant code snippets of where the error is occurring:

The builder function to pass all the necessary props to the D3 library

```
const buildModelVisual = (dataPoints) => {
    console.log("category: " + dataPoints[0].category)
    console.log("range: " + dataPoints[0].range)
    console.log("frequency: " + dataPoints[0].frequency)
    dataPoints[0].frequency.forEach(f => 
        console.log("f: " + f)
    )
    const width = 960,
        height = 500,
        margins = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50},
        id = "model-visual",
        title = "NaiveBayes Model Visual",
        svgClassName = "model-visual-class",
        titleClassName = "model-visual-title-class",
        legendClassName = "model-legend",
        showLegend = true,
        showXAxis = true,
        showYAxis = true,
        showXGrid = false,
        showYGrid = false,
        ranges = [
            ...dataPoints[0].range
        ],
        frequencies = [
            ...dataPoints[0].frequency
        ],
        x = () => {
            return ranges.forEach(r => {
                return r;
            })
        },
        xOrient = 'bottom',
        xTickOrient = 'bottom'
    
    const xDomain = dataPoints[0].range.forEach(r => {
        return {
            category: dataPoints[0].category, range: r
        }
        }),
        xRangeRoundBands = {interval: [0, width - margins.left - margins.right], padding: 0.1},
        xScale = 'ordinal',
        xAxisClassName = 'x-axis',
        xLabel = dataPoints[0].category,
        xLabelPosition = 'bottom',
        xTickPadding = 3,
        xInnerTickSize = 6,
        xOuterTickSize = 6,
        y = () => {
            return frequencies.forEach(freqInRange => {
                return freqInRange.forEach(f => {
                    return f;
                });
            })
        },
        yOrient = 'left',
        yTickOrient = 'left',
        yRange = [height - margins.top - margins.bottom, 0]

    const yDomain = [0, d3.max(
            dataPoints[0].frequency,
            (f) => {
                return f.value
            }
        )],
        yScale = 'linear',
        yAxisClassName = 'y-axis',
        yLabel = "Population",
        yTickFormat = d3.format(".2s"),
        yLabelPosition = 'left',
        yTickPadding = 4,
        yInnerTickSize = 6,
        yOuterTickSize = 6

    return (
        <Chart
        title={title}
        id={id}
        width={width}
        height={height}
        >
        <BarStackChart
          title= {title}
          data= {ranges}
          width= {width}
          height= {height}
          id= {id}
          margins= {margins}
          svgClassName= {svgClassName}
          titleClassName= {titleClassName}
          yAxisClassName= {yAxisClassName}
          xAxisClassName= {xAxisClassName}
          legendClassName= {legendClassName}
          categoricalColors= {d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)}
          chartSeries = {ranges}
          showLegend= {showLegend}
          showXAxis= {showXAxis}
          showYAxis= {showYAxis}
          x= {x}
          showXGrid= {showXGrid}
          xDomain= {xDomain}
          xRangeRoundBands= {xRangeRoundBands}
          xScale= {xScale}
          xOrient= {xOrient}
          xTickOrient= {xTickOrient}
          xTickPadding = {xTickPadding}
          xInnerTickSize = {xInnerTickSize}
          xOuterTickSize = {xOuterTickSize}
          xLabel = {xLabel}
          xLabelPosition = {xLabelPosition}
          y= {y}
          showYGrid= {showYGrid}
          yOrient= {yOrient}
          yRange= {yRange}
          yDomain= {yDomain}
          yScale= {yScale}
          yTickOrient= {yTickOrient}
          yTickPadding = {yTickPadding}
          yInnerTickSize = {yInnerTickSize}
          yOuterTickSize = {yOuterTickSize}
          yTickFormat= {yTickFormat}
          yLabel = {yLabel}
          yLabelPosition = {yLabelPosition}
        />
      </Chart>
    )
}
```

The HO class component that is rendering the graph and the interface

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.ref = React.createRef();
        this.state = {
            input: "",
            output: [],
            visual: null
        }
    }
```

REST API call (within the default class Component) that sets the data for the BarStackChart

```
callGetModel = () => {
        let getModelRanges = getCall(ApiURL.get_model_ranges);
        let getModelFrequencies = getCall(ApiURL.get_model_frequencies);
        Promise.all([getModelRanges, getModelFrequencies]).then(data => {
            this.setState({output: data})
            const dataPoints = [];

            for (let value in JSON.parse(data[0].toString())) {
                dataPoints.push({
                    category: value,
                    range: JSON.parse(data[0].toString())[value],
                    frequency: JSON.parse(data[1].toString())[value]
                })
            }

            console.log(dataPoints)

            const ModelVisual = buildModelVisual(dataPoints)

            this.setState({ visual: ModelVisual }) // returns JSX element 

            console.log(this.state.visual)
        });
    }
```

The render method for the class Component

```
    render() {
        return <div>
            <h3>Welcome to Naive Bayes Java!</h3>
            <p>The REST API for this project is hosted at</p>
            <a style={{'display':'block', 'paddingBottom':'1.5em', 'color':'rgb(0, 150, 196)'}} href="https://naivebayesjava.herokuapp.com/swagger-ui.html#/">https://naivebayesjava.herokuapp.com/</a>
            <button style={{'display':'inline', 'background':'rgb(32, 32, 32)', 'color':'rgb(190, 190, 190)'}} onClick={this.callListOfFiles}>
                Get List of Valid Files
            </button>
            <button style={{'background':'rgb(32, 32, 32)', 'color':'rgb(190, 190, 190)'}} onClick={this.callGetModel}>
                Get Model
            </button>
            <button style={{'background':'rgb(32, 32, 32)', 'color':'rgb(190, 190, 190)'}} onClick={this.callGetModelAccuracy}>
                Get Model Accuracy
            </button>
            <div style={{'margin':'auto', 'display':'block'}}>
                <input style={{'background':'rgb(32, 32, 32)', 'color':'rgb(190, 190, 190)'}} type='text' value={this.state.input} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <button style={{'background':'rgb(32, 32, 32)', 'color':'rgb(190, 190, 190)'}} onClick={this.callSetData}>
                    Set Training Data File
                </button>
            </div>
            {/* <button onClick={this.callGetTrainingData}>
                Get Training Data Arff Files
            </button> */}
            <div style={{'padding-top':'0.5em'}} ref={this.ref}></div>
            <output type='textBox' style={{ 'padding':'1.25em', 'display':'block', 'Height': '30px', 'Width': '300px' }}>
            { Object.keys(this.state.output).map(key => {
                return this.state.output[key]                
            }) }
            </output>
            { this.state.visual }
        </div>
    }
```

There most definitely is a better way to implement this besides setting a "this.state.visual" JSX Element and calling that in the render method, although as I am really new to both React (started learning about a month ago) and JS (started about 3 months ago) I don't quite know all the common practices with either; just the general theory behind how they work.

This interface and my portfolio are hosted at [joshuabaroni.github.io](https://joshuabaroni.github.io) . The interface i am attempting to improve is the NaiveBayes Project Interface under the "Projects" section

Any recommendations would be appreciated! the whole JS file is available upon request.

Comment: It's difficult to understand where the error is actually happening. That said: `            this.setState({ visual: ModelVisual }); console.log(this.state.visual)` ignores that `setState` is asynchronous, and since it is, you may be attempting to render `this.state.visual` before it's been set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined
> in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

You aren't exporting your classes/functions as it is required.

Exporting without default means it's a "named export". You can have multiple named exports in a single file. So if you do this,

```
class Template {}
class AnotherTemplate {}
export { Template, AnotherTemplate } // named export
```

then you have to import these exports using their exact names. So to use these components in another file you'd have to do,

```
import {Template, AnotherTemplate} from './components/templates'
```

Alternatively if you export as the default export like this,

```
export default class Template {}
```

Then in another file you import the default export without using the {}, like this,

```
import Template from './components/templates'
```

There can only be one default export per file. In React it's a convention to export one component from a file, and to export it is as the default export.

You're free to rename the default export as you import it,

```
import TheTemplate from './components/templates'
```

And you can import default and named exports at the same time,

```
import Template,{AnotherTemplate} from './components/templates'
```